# How to represent binary data in 8 bits in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long int decimalNumber,remainder,quotient;
    int binaryNumber[100],i=1,j;

    printf("Enter any decimal number: ");
    scanf("%ld",&decimalNumber);
    quotient = decimalNumber;

    while(quotient!=0)
    {
        binaryNumber[i++]= quotient % 2;
        quotient = quotient / 2;
    }

    printf("Equivalent binary value of decimal number %d: ",decimalNumber);

    for(j = i -1 ;j> 0;j--)
        printf("%d",binaryNumber[j]);

    return 0;
}
```

I want the output in 8 bit binary form, but the result as shown below, is there any operator in C which can convert 7 bit data to its equivalent 8 bit data? thank you

Sample output:

> Enter any decimal number: 50
>
> Equivalent binary value of decimal number 50: 110010

Required output is `00110010` which is 8 bit, how to append a zero in MSB position?

Comment: Do you mean you want it in blocks of 8 bits? Because your "any decimal number" won't fit into 8 bits.

Comment: You have to keep track of how long your actual binary number is (helper variable mb?) and after you see that decide how many zeroes to append at the beginning.

Comment: If your number was 64 to 255 it would work. You are generating just enough digits to represent the number. There's a few ways to deal with that...

Answer (score 3):

A very convenient way it so have a function return a binary representation in the form of a string. This allows the binary representation to be used within a normal `printf` format string rather than having the bits spit out at the current cursor position. To specify the exact number of digits, you must pad the binary string to the required number of places (e.g. 8, 16, 32...). The following makes use of a `static` variable to allow the return of the buffer,  but the same can easily be implemented by allocating space for the buffer with dynamically. The preprocessor checks are not required as you can simply hardwire the length of the buffer to `64 + 1`, but for the sake of completeness a check for `x86/x86_64` is included and `BITS_PER_LONG` is set accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#if defined(__LP64__) || defined(_LP64)
# define BUILD_64   1
#endif

#ifdef BUILD_64
# define BITS_PER_LONG 64
#else
# define BITS_PER_LONG 32
#endif

char *binstr (unsigned long n, size_t sz);

int main (void) {

    printf ("\n 50 (decimal)  :  %s (binary)\n\n", binstr (50, 8));

    return 0;
}

/* returns pointer to binary representation of 'n' zero padded to 'sz'. */
char *binstr (unsigned long n, size_t sz)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;
    register size_t i;

    if (!n) {
        *s = '0';
        return s;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sz; i++)
        *(--p) = (n>>i & 1) ? '1' : '0';

    return p;
}
```

**Output**

```
$ ./bin/bincnv

 50 (decimal)  :  00110010 (binary)
```

**Note:** you cannot make repeated calls in the same `printf` statement due to the static buffer. If you allocate dynamically, you can call the function as many times as you like in the same `printf` statement.

Also, note, if you do not care about padding the binary return to any specific length and just want the binary representation to start with the most significant bit, the following simpler version can be used:

```
/* simple return of binary string */
char *binstr (unsigned long n)
{
    static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = {0};
    char *p = s + BITS_PER_LONG;

    if (!n) {
        *s = '0';
        return s;
    }

    while (n) {
        *(--p) = (n & 1) ? '1' : '0';
        n >>= 1;
    }
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Good answer!  I can understand in sql level: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=f869fff73a1c60f480e88b28e74733a6 I can aslo understand right shift. But somehow, I am not total get the `--p`. since p is twice size of BITS_PER_LONG.  first the char *p first parts will be all 0 then in the end will be "00110010"?

Comment: @Mark `p` is a character pointer (`sizeof (any_pointer)`).  So you are just using a pointer -- Initially set to point at the end of the string `s` to fill `s` from the end -- so that your binary string is in the proper order.  Initially `s` is initialized all zero (could use `static char s[BITS_PER_LONG + 1] = "";`) Since pre-increment is used on `p` (e.g. `--p`) the 1st assignment is to the next to last char is `s` (leaving the nul-terminating char in place). After the string has been filled `p` is returned providing a pointer to the first filled char in `s` (the string that begins there)

Answer (score 2):

Modify your code as shown below:

```
  quotient = quotient / 2;
}
/* ---- Add the following code ---- */
{
  int group_size = 8;  /* Or CHAR_BIT */
  int padding = group_size  - ((i-1) % group_size); /* i was inited with 1 */
  if(padding != group_size) {
     /* Add padding */
     while(padding-- != 0) binaryNumber[i++] = 0;
  }
}
/* ------- Modification ends -------- */
printf("Equivalent binary value of decimal number %d: ",decimalNumber);
```

This code calculates the number of [padding bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment#Computing_padding) required to print the number and fills the padding bits with 0.

[Live demo here](http://ideone.com/lE7y0C)

If you want 7 bit answer, change `group_size` to 7.

Comment: I'll be glad if it helps you :)

Answer (score 1):

Use this for printing your result:

```
for(j = 7; j>0; j--)
    printf("%d", binaryNumber[j]);
```

This always prints 8 binary digits.

---

**Edit**

The int array `binaryNumber` must be initialized with zeros to make this work:

```
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) binaryNumber[i] = 0;
```

Comment: And in case it is a negative number? Then you'd want leading ones.

Comment: If you want to handle `signed int` you need a different algorithm. OP's algorithm is designed for `unsigned int`

Comment: @Beko: Why not. Does it not depend on what the OP really want? What if the OP wants a leading 1 to be a sign bit?

Comment: The bit array must be initialized to `0` for this to work. The OP's code only outputs defined values, yours does not.

Comment: @DrKoch How did you come to that conclusion? The way I see it it has to work for "any decimal" number. @ slebetman Well, I was assuming that it'd be 2's complement. But yeah, it depends on what he actually wants.